# Profiling Javascript code using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, ejs

I am working on a system that pre-generates pages of a CanJS application. That way our pages are instantly available and we do not need to take care of SEO stuff with #! and headless browsers.

The problem is that performance of [rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Rhino) seems to be dramatically slower than a V8 or other native Javascript engines used inside modern browsers. While inside the browsers, the page needs 3 - 4 seconds to generate the EJS template at worst, [rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Rhino) needs 10 - 12 **minutes**. Both the page and the generator are using the same JSON gathered from a RESTful API.

I created a Javascript context using the highest optimization level:

```
context = ContextFactory.getGlobal().
context.setOptimizationLevel(9);
scope = context.initStandardObjects();
scriptable = context.newObject(scope);
```

To invoke the EJS rendering process using the current [EJS library](http://embeddedjs.com)

```
function invokeEjs(ejsContent, parameters){
    try{
        var unwrap = eval('new Object(' + parameters + ')');
        return new EJS({
            text: ejsContent
        }).render(unwrap);
    } catch(e){
        return outputException(e, ejsContent);
    } 
}
```

Now once I call this method it takes ages.

```
HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// ...
// ... loading some content into parameters hashmap
// ...
String ejsTemplate = "... a pre loaded ejs template from file ..."
String serializedParameters = jsonParser.toJson(parameters);
Function fct = (Function) scope.get("invokeEjs", scope);
Object resultTemp = fct.call(context, scriptable, scriptable, new Object[] { ejsTemplate, serializedParameters });
```

The **serializedParameters** can get really big, but this doesn't bother the browser and I expect the Rhino implementation not to take more than twice the time.

I am currently stuck here and do not know how to proceed. How to profile what takes that much time? What can be the cause?

Comment: Don't use Rhino. Its slow as hell. Look at node.js or Phantom.js

Comment: mh ok would fit since I could use javascript natively... to bad there is not fast interpreter. But in that case switching to nodejs and got a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005849/using-steal-in-nodejs-application-to-resolve-dependencies

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measuring and benchmarking processing power of a javascript engine in a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128057/measuring-and-benchmarking-processing-power-of-a-javascript-engine-in-a-browser)